# Multiple parallel calls to WCF Service takes longer than single call

Tags: c#, wcf, task-parallel-library

I'm testing WCF concurrency and instancing.

There is wcf Service :

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

}
```

From my forms application I make call to this service method. When I do single call, it takes aprox: 1 sec as expected.

```
    private void single_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var service = new Service1Client())
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            service.GetData(1);
            sw.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
        }
    }
```

But when I call it multiple times with Tasks, it takes aprox : call count * 1 second.

```
    private void mult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var service = new Service1Client())
        {
           var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
           for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
           {

              int p = i;
              tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => service.GetData(p)));
           }


           var sw = new Stopwatch();
           sw.Start();
           Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
           sw.Stop();
           Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

           foreach (var task in tasks)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine(task.Result);
           }


        }
    }
```

I've tried all 9 combinations of Instancing and Concurrency (`Instance mode = Per Call and Concurrency = Single` etc.)

Interesting thing is that if I create new ServiceClient object for all Task, it works fine, but I don't think it is right approach. I feel that there must be some thing I missed.If so,  Can you tell me what exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is on the client side.

You have to explicitly call `Open()` on the `Service1Client` object before making any calls to the service. Otherwise your WCF client proxy is internally going to have a call to `EnsureOpened()`. The problem is specifically that `EnsureOpened()` will result in each request waiting until the previous request is completed before executing and this is why only one request will be sent out at a time and not in parallel as desired.

Change your code like this:

```
using (var service = new Service1Client())
{
    service.Open();
    // Do stuff...
}
```

From **Wenlong Dong's** excellent [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/26/best-practice-always-open-wcf-client-proxy-explicitly-when-it-is-shared.aspx) on the subject:

> If you don’t call the “Open” method first, the proxy would be opened
>   internally when the first call is made on the proxy. This is called
>   auto-open. Why? When the first message is sent through the auto-opened
>   proxy, it will cause the proxy to be opened automatically. You can use
>   .NET Reflector to open the method
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call and see the following
>   code:
>
> ```
> if (!this.explicitlyOpened)
>   {
>          this.EnsureDisplayUI();
>          this.EnsureOpened(rpc.TimeoutHelper.RemainingTime());
>   }
> ```
>
> When you drill down into EnsureOpened, you will see that it calls
>   CallOnceManager.CallOnce. For non-first calls, you would hit
>   SyncWait.Wait which waits for the first request to complete. This
>   mechanism is to ensure that all requests wait for the proxy to be
>   opened and it also ensures the correct execution order. Thus all
>   requests are serialized into a single execution sequence until all
>   requests are drained out from the queue. This is not a desired
>   behavior in most cases.

Comment: After 10 years of on/off WCF I run into this. I wish I had never opened ServiceChannel in reflector.

Comment: Additionally, you need to `Open` a different object for EVERY concurrent call you make. You cannot simply open one object and perform multiple concurrent calls on it. Realizing this took me quite some time.